# Ruby 1.8.7: intercepting chained methods for object

Tags: ruby, methods, method-chaining

I have a class that is wrapping cells of arbitrary data; sort of a filter.  The cells live in a backend datastore. but that should be as transparent as possible.

Writing straightforward accessors is simple enough:

```
def foo
  # fetch backend cell value and return it
end
def foo=(val)
  # store val in backend cell
end
```

The part I'm finding tricky is intercepting and tracking methods that would ordinarily affect the data if it weren't wrapped.  For instance, if the data is an array, `obj.foo << 17` would add an element to the array *in situ*.  I want to maintain that behaviour on the data stored in the backend (*i.e.*, `obj.foo << 17` results in the stored value having an element added as well).  I thought perhaps a `method_missing` would help:

```
def method_missing(meth, *args)
  methsym = meth.to_sym
  curval = self.get
  lastval = curval.clone
  opresult = curval.__send__(methsym, *args)
  if (curval != lastval)
    self.set(curval)
  end
  return opresult
end
```

but in combination with the reader accessor, control of the operation has moved beyond me because the thing it returns is **not** the thing itself.  (*I.e.*, if the backend data is an array, I'm returning a *copy* of it, and it's the copy that's being modified and never sent back to me.)

Is this possible?  If so, how can I do it?  (It's probably painfully obvious and I'm just missing it because I'm tired -- or maybe not. :-)

Thanks!

**[edited]**

To put it another way..  `#method_missing` allows you to hook into the invocation process for unknown methods.  I'm looking for a way to hook into the invocation process similarly, but for *all* methods, known **and** unknown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by borrowing from the `Delegator` module.  (Code that follows is **not** guaranteed to work; I've edited out some details by hand.  But it should supply the gist.)

- On a fetch (reader accessor), annotate the value to be passed back with modified methods:

  ```
  def enwrap(target)
    #
    # Shamelessly cadged from delegator.rb
    #
    eigenklass = eval('class << target ; self ; end')
    preserved = ::Kernel.public_instance_methods(false)
    preserved -= [ 'to_s', 'to_a', 'inspect', '==', '=~', '===' ]
    swbd = {}
    target.instance_variable_set(:@_method_map, swbd)
    target.instance_variable_set(:@_datatype, target.class)
    for t in self.class.ancestors
      preserved |= t.public_instance_methods(false)
      preserved |= t.private_instance_methods(false)
      preserved |= t.protected_instance_methods(false)
    end
    preserved << 'singleton_method_added'
    target.methods.each do |method|
      next if (preserved.include?(method))
      swbd[method] = target.method(method.to_sym)
      target.instance_eval(<<-EOS)
        def #{method}(*args, &block)
          iniself = self.clone
          result = @_method_map['#{method}'].call(*args, &block)
          if (self != iniself)
            #
            # Store the changed entity
            #
            newklass = self.class
            iniklass = iniself.instance_variable_get(:@_datatype)
            unless (self.kind_of?(iniklass))
              begin
                raise RuntimeError('Class mismatch')
              rescue RuntimeError
                if ($@)
                  $@.delete_if { |s|
                    %r"\A#{Regexp.quote(__FILE__)}:\d+:in `" =~ s
                  }
                end
                raise
              end
            end
            # update back end here
          end
          return result
        end
      EOS
    end
  end                         # End of def enwrap
  ```
- On a store (writer accessor), strip the singleton methods we added:

  ```
  def unwrap(target)
    remap = target.instance_variable_get(:@_method_map)
    return nil unless (remap.kind_of?(Hash))
    remap.keys.each do |method|
      begin
        eval("class << target ; remove_method(:#{method}) ; end")
      rescue
      end
    end
    target.instance_variable_set(:@_method_map, nil)
    target.instance_variable_set(:@_datatype, nil)
  end                        # End of def unwrap
  ```

So when the value is requested, it gets 'wrapper' methods added to it before being returned, and the singletons are removed before anything is stored in the back end.  Any operations that change the value will also update the back end as a side-effect.

There *are* some unfortunate side-side-effects of this technique as currently implemented.  Assume that the class with the wrapped variables is instantiated in `backend`, and that one of the variables is accessed *via* `ivar_foo`:

```
backend.ivar_foo
=> nil
backend.ivar_foo = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1,2,3]
bar = backend.ivar_foo
=> [1,2,3]
bar << 4
=> [1,2,3,4]
backend.ivar_foo = 'string'
=> "string"
bar
=> [1,2,3,4]
backend.ivar_foo
=> "string"
bar.pop
=> 4
bar
=> [1,2,3]
backend.ivar_foo
=> [1,2,3]
```

But that's more of a curiousity than a problem for me at the moment. :-)

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to wrap each object returned by your class inside a meta object which is aware of the  backend, and could update it as needed.

In your example, you'd need to return an array wrapper object which could handle inserts, deletes, etc.

--- Edit ---

Instead of creating lots of wrapper classes, you may be able to add a 'singleton method' to the returned objects, especially if you can easily identify the methods that might need special handling.

```
module BackEndIF
  alias :old_send :__send__
  def __send__ method, *args
    if MethodsThatNeedSpecialHandling.include?(method)
       doSpecialHandling()
    else
      old_send(method,args)
    end
  end
end

#in your class:
def foo
   data = Backend.fetch(query)
   data.extend(BackEndIF)
   return data
end
```

<strike>I don't think anything based on method-missing will work, since the objects you are returning do have the methods in question.  (i.e. Array does have an operator<<, it's not missing)</strike>

Or, maybe you can do something with a `method_missing` like the one you outline. 
Create a single meta_object something like this:

```
class DBobject
   def initialize(value, db_reference)
      @value = value
      @ref = db_reference
    end
   def method_missing(meth, *args)
     old_val = @value
     result = @value.__send__(meth, *args)
     DatabaseUpdate(@ref, @value) if (@value != old_val)
     return result   
   end
end
```

Then `foo` returns a `DBObject.new(objectFromDB, referenceToDB)`.

Comment: Meh.  I was hoping for something better than that, because I want the backendedness to remain as transparent as possible.  I need to investigate `method_missing` with no read accessor..  Thanks!

Comment: The `#extend` technique looks promising, but in Ruby 1.8.7 `#__send__` doesn't appear to be invoked for all defined methods.  *I.e.*, if `Foo` has a method `#bar`, `Foo.new.bar` won't go through any `#__send__` defined in `Foo`.

Comment: `Delegator` seems unlikely, at least out of the box.  It appears to fail the `#kind_of?` test; "`SimpleDelegator.new([]).kind_of?(Array) => false`".  It has all of `Array`'s methods, but doesn't admit to (*i.e.*, fake) the inheritance.

Comment: I have a solution that pulled in aspects of all of these; I will be adding it as the accepted answer later today. @AShelly thanks!!!